# how to save image downloaded from url(server) to local folder in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, download, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

i am trying to download images from server and save it in local file.
i tried

```
 private async void save()
    {

        Uri source = new Uri("http://www.google.ca/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png");
        StorageFile destinationFile;
        try
        {
            destinationFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                "downloadimage.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("bingooooo"+ex.ToString());
            return;
        }
        BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);
        await download.StartAsync();
        ResponseInformation response = download.GetResponseInformation();



    }
```

but it doesn't work any alternative

Comment: Please define `it doesn't work`. That tells us absolutely nothing about the issues you're encountering. Runtime exception? Compile error? Unexpected result? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? Be more specific.

Comment: no error message i cant see the image file in the debug folder

Comment: @suvishvalsan The image is not going to be downloaded in the Debug folder but in Local storage which will be in C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Packages\<PackageId>\LocalState

Comment: thanks benoit for support

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, it's just lacking `Task` as return type. You should use return type as `Task` rather than `void` if your method is asynchronous. If return type is `string` & method is asynchronous then return type should be `Task<string>`.

Change `private async void save()` to `private async Task save()`.

When you call `save()` append `await` keyword.

Check out [Diving deep with WinRT and await](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/24/diving-deep-with-winrt-and-await.aspx)